# merging polygons of a SpatialPolygonDataframe

Tags: r, spatial, rgdal, r-maptools

I have created a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame in which countries are associated with regions. Here is what it looks like https://cloudstor.aarnet.edu.au/plus/index.php/s/RpYr3xyMrmhaGKA (EDU link with data):

[image]

As the object is too large to work with and as I am only interested in the information regions and not countries, I wish to merge the countries within each region. In other words, I wish to create a single polygon for each region.
I have tried to run the following commands but the runs take hours and I have never been able to see whether they worked properly.

```
library(rgdal)
regions = readOGR("./regionscountriesSTACK.shp")
library(maptools)
regions <- unionSpatialPolygons(regions, IDs=regions@data$REGION)
library(rgeos)
gUnionCascaded(regions, id = regions@data$REGION)
gUnaryUnion(regions, id = regions@data$REGION)
```

Any advise on an efficient way to process? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I have just added the link to the shapefile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to:
1) simplify the polygons, they likely are too complex to begin with, specially if you want to aggregate them by region. Use `gSimplify` from rgeos package. Hard to help you further without the data. 
2) remove the holes, they take up a lot of space and lead to troubles when you simplify
3) do the union and simplification with allowing for a serious simplification of the data

The following codes combines all of that, doing it country by country also allows to see the progress of the thing:

```
library(rgdal)
library(maptools)
library(rgeos)

# Remove all holes that are bigger than "limitholes", by default all of them
RemoveHoles <- function(SPol,limitHoles=+Inf){
    fn <- function(subPol){
        if(subPol@hole && subPol@area < limitHoles) 
            keep <- FALSE
        else
            keep <- TRUE
        return(keep)
    }
    nPol <- length(SPol)
    newPols <- list()
    for(iPol in 1:nPol){
        subPolygons <- list()
        pol <- SPol@polygons[[iPol]]
        for(iSubPol in 1:length(pol@Polygons)){
            subPol <- pol@Polygons[[iSubPol]]

            if(fn(subPol))
                subPolygons[[length(subPolygons)+1]] <- subPol
        }
        newPols[[length(newPols)+1]] <- Polygons(subPolygons,pol@ID)
    }
    newSPol <- SpatialPolygons(newPols,proj4string=CRS(proj4string(SPol)))
    # SPolSimple <- gSimplify(newSPol,tol=0.01)
    newSPol <- createSPComment(newSPol)
    return(newSPol)
}

# Union Polygon (country) by polygon for a given region
UnionSimplifyPolByPol <- function(subReg,precision=0.2){
    # if(length(subReg)>1){
    #     out <- unionSpatialPolygons(subReg[1:2,],rep(1,2),threshold=0.1)
    #     out <- RemoveHoles(out)
    # }
    out <- c()
    for(iCountry in 1:length(subReg)){
        cat("Adding:",subReg@data[iCountry,"COUNTRY"],"\n") 
        toAdd <- gSimplify(as(subReg[iCountry,],"SpatialPolygons"),
                           tol=precision,topologyPreserve=TRUE)
        toAdd <- RemoveHoles(toAdd)
        if(is.null(out)){
            out <- toAdd
        }else{
            toUnite <- rbind(out,toAdd)
            out <- unionSpatialPolygons(toUnite,
                                        IDs=rep(1,2),
                                        threshold=precision)
        }
        out <- RemoveHoles(out)
        # plot(out)
    }
    return(out)
}
# import the data
countries <- readOGR("regionscountriesSTACK.shp")

# you don't want to be bothered by factors
countries@data$COUNTRY <- as.character(countries@data$COUNTRY)
countries@data$REGION <- as.character(countries@data$REGION)

# aggregate region by region  
vectRegions <- unique(countries@data$REGION)
world <- c()
for(iRegion in 1:length(vectRegions)){
    regionName <- vectRegions[iRegion]
    cat("Region:",regionName)
    region <- UnionSimplifyPolByPol(countries[which(countries$REGION==regionName),])
    region <- spChFIDs(region,regionName)
    if(is.null(world)){
        world <- region
    }else{
        world <- rbind(world,region)
    }
    plot(world)
}
```

[image]

This solution is implemented in the package [spatDataManagement](https://bitbucket.org/cmbce/r-package-spatdatamanagement). Also you may want to use `rworldmap` for a lighter world map if you are only interested by the regions. It then becomes:

```
library("spatDataManagement")
library("rworldmap")
levels(countriesLow@data$REGION)<-c(levels(countriesLow@data$REGION),"Other")
countriesLow@data$REGION[which(is.na(countriesLow@data$REGION))] <- "Other"

vectRegions <- unique(countriesLow@data$REGION)
world <- c()
for(iRegion in 1:length(vectRegions)){
    regionName <- vectRegions[iRegion]
    cat("Region:",regionName)
    region <- UnionSimplifyPolByPol(countriesLow[which(countriesLow$REGION==regionName),])
    region <- spChFIDs(region,gsub(" ","",regionName)) # IDs can't have spaces
    if(is.null(world)){
        world <- region
    }else{
        world <- rbind(world,region)
    }
}
world <- SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(world,data.frame(id=1:length(world),name=vectRegions),match.ID=FALSE)
plot(world,col=world$id)
```

[image]

And this new map is much, much smaller (2.8 MegaBytes).

Comment: Thanks a lot! gSimplify creates a SpatialPolygons, thus I loose the information on the regions and don't know how to then apply gUnaryUnion for instance. Any help welcome. I've also attached the .shp file.

Comment: @Cecile, je n'arrive pas à ouvrir ce document (manque les autres fichiers compagnon du shp comme le shx ?).

Comment: Merci de votre aide! je viens de modifier le lien vers les fichiers. Just added the correct data source.

Comment: Now I can download and open it. What kind of treatment do you want to do after the union ?

Comment: Hi! I wish to associate a range of coordinates in a dataframe with their corresponding region. `temp <- extract(regions,cbind(df$long, df$lat), df=TRUE, method='simple', cellnumbers=T )` `df <- cbind(temp,df)`. I have added a sample dataframe to the link, in case you wish to have a look